# Name or proof of generalisation of Pythagorean Theorem (similar figures on the sides of a right triangle)

Tags: geometry

I have found a result that generalizes Pythagorean theorem, and I'm looking for a proof for the result. It is stated, for example, here http://www.jaconline.com.au/mathsquestqld/book2/downloads/investigations/MQQLD2-pythagoras.pdf

Do anyone know where I can find a proof?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what it is that you are asking.  What is it, exactly, that you are looking for a proof of?  Can you state proposition that you want to prove?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ItiFO5y36kw  numberphile has a video you might like for a possible name.

Comment: That Pythagorean theorem generalizes for similar figures, @Xander

Comment: Euclid provided two proofs of the Pythagorean theorem: the second one is more general and is exactly the generalization you are looking for. You can find that proof here: https://www.cut-the-knot.org/pythagoras/index.shtml#7. It is indeed the same proof attributed to Polya in the answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This observation is equivalent to the Pythagorean theorem and provides an alternative proof. The logic depends on the fact that areas of similar figures scale with the square of the linear dimensions - itself equivalent to the Pythagorean theorem and to the parallel postulate. I first learned this from Polya: see page 15-17 here:

http://uberty.org/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/Polya_Mathematics_and_Plausible_Reasoning1.pdf

[image]

Comment: I like the numberphile video I commented with more I think.

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee The video is indeed nice. I'm old enough to prefer the Polya text.

Comment: This proof was indeed devised by Euclid himself, see:  https://www.cut-the-knot.org/pythagoras/index.shtml#7.